# Windows: how cmd finds an executable not in path?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, php, environment-variables

From a Windows 7 command line (opened from any directory), if I type `php -v`, it will execute `C:\php\php.exe` and show version information.

I can't figure out how the system knows what `php` is, since when I look at my Path ([as described here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm#windows7)), the `C:\php` folder is not there.

I noticed that in the Environment Variables screen, the top half has another Path variable in a section named "*user variables for Admin*", but the PHP directory is not there either.

How does Windows 7 know where to find `php.exe`?

Comment: What paths have been define in the system variable?

Comment: @Ramhound This is silly. After reading your Q, I went back and inserted each path on a new line, and lo-and-behold, one of them was `c:\php`.  It was just stuck in a wall of text and I couldn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact there are many possibilities, e.g. you can "register" the location in the registry, there could be a batch/script on the path that knows the real location of the executable (both described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822400/register-an-exe-so-you-can-run-it-from-any-command-line-in-windows), or it's in your user path (opposed to the system path).
Type `PATH` on the command line prompt to check was really on your environment path.